How I can test location service, and it's permissions with junit?
Is it possible to write to write instrumental tests and later on for location permissions? I'm relatively new to testing topic, and I haven't found much examples that could possibly help me with it.

Of course it is. What do you have so far? Please provide the parts of the code where you have problems with and narrow your question to a specific problem.
